# How to make the height of container div responsive?

Tags: css

I played a bit with different values trying to make this div responive and figured out how to make the width responsive but height doesn't work on the phones and tablets. I use **vh** units whether I should use percentages or the problem isn't in units?
[div on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8erQi.png). [div in on the desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBaBG.jpg)P.S (if someone want to check it) dev-tools — ctrl+shift+I then device-toolbar — ctrl+shift+M. Would appreciate any feedback or advices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Train yourself!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ttt.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="artblock">
   <div class="painting tl o"></div>
   <div class="painting t"></div>
   <div class="painting th"></div>
   <div class="painting bl fo"></div>
   <div class="painting tr fi"></div>
   <div class="painting si"></div>
   <div class="painting se"></div>
   <div class="painting br ei"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

   CSS
 body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
 }
 .artblock {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 244px;
   width: 50%;
   max-height: 608px;
   height: 83vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   box-shadow: 8px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -8px -5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
   position: relative;
   top: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .painting {
   max-width: 120px;
   width: 50%;
   max-height:150px;
   height: 20.47vh;
   border: 1px solid #1D1E18;
 }

 .tl {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
 }
 .tr {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
 }
 .bl {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
 }
 .br {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
 .o{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/1.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .t{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/2.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .th{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/3.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .fo{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/4.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .fi{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/5.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .si{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/6.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .se{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/7.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .ei{
     background-image: url("/TrainingCss/img/8.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few attempts I finally make this div responsive!
After I discovered **calc()** function for myself (this function calculates the result depending on the entered data )it became possible to make the height responsive. I just took the width of container div, took away 8px(total  borders height) and divided the result by 4. Heres the code:

```
.painting {
  max-width: 120px;
  width: 50%;
  max-height:150px;
  height:calc((84vh - 8px)/4);
  border: 1px solid #1D1E18;
}
```